# Logs return object not found in firebase storage but it exist in the firebase storage console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I got the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'Bakery/Bakery Cuisine' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
```

But last I checked:

[image]

The path is there and I just uploaded a file in like 30 mins ago. So how come firebase storage is saying it does not exist?

What I want to do: To be able to download the content insid all the .txt files under the path of `paramKey` and then display out that content for users to see.

Code:

```
const [toReadfb, setToReadDatafb] = useState([])
useEffect (() => {
    const rfb = sRef(storage, paramKey)
    const output = getDownloadURL(rfb)
    .then(function (url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        var blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    });
    setToReadDatafb(output)
  }, [])
  console.log(toReadfb)
```

My logs from `toReadfb`

```
{"_1": 0, "_2": 0, "_3": null, "_4": null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bakery/Bakery Cuisine` in your screenshot is a folder, not a file. There is no way to retrieve the download URL of a folder.

The `Post60e...5ea` in your screenshot is a file. If you want to retrieve that file, you'll need to pass its entire path (so: `Bakery/Bakery Cuisine/Post60e...5ea`).

If you want to get a list of the files in a folder, have a look at the Firebae documentation on [listing files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files).

Comment: Is there any official video about this to watch to understand how it works? Also is it possible to get not just all files in the folder but the content of all the files in the folder and display it?

Comment: 1) There are tons of videos about the Cloud Storage APIs from Firebase, but if you're just looking for code that works there really isn't anything beter than the documentation I linked.  2) Getting the files in a folder is a of calling the `list` API I linked, and then looping over the results as shown in that same link to find a reference to each file and do with that what you need.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information ! I have tried it but it isnt really working, is it possible to help me take a look and guide me on how to correct the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718011/unable-to-retrieve-url-and-all-the-files-from-firebase-storage-via-react-native