# Unable to retrieve URL and all the files from Firebase storage via react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I have the following code:

```
import { uploadString, getDownloadURL, listAll } from 'firebase/storage';
 const listRef = sRef(storage, paramKey)
  // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        // All the prefixes under listRef.
        // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
      });
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        // All the items under listRef.
        console.log("ItemRef: " + itemRef)
        itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url =>{
          console.log("Download Url: " + url)
        }))
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      console.log(error)
    });
  return (
```

This is to retrieve all the files in a particular folder. At the same time to get the download url of each file.

All I get is the following:

[image]

In the firebase storage console, I have 4 things:

[image]

1. How come I am just getting one thing back instead of 4 things for ItemRef? Shouldnt it be all 4 instead of 1?
2. How come the url is not appearing at all? I have imported `getDownloadURL` already but when I took a closer look at my code, `getDownloadURL` is not highlighted which means unused. So I copy and paste `getDownloadURL` from the import to my function but it is still not highlighted. How come?

The import is telling me it is declared but value not read:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your `import` statement, the `getDownloadURL` is a global function - not a method on a reference to a file. So you'll want to use it like this:

```
getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url =>{
  console.log("Download Url: " + url)
}))
```

This is pretty similar to the code sample in the documentation on [downloading a file through a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#web-version-9_1), so I recommend keeping the v9 documentation handy while coding.